# Session doesn't hold custom userdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I started to use the session library.

I have autoloaded the session library and trying to save the current user_id to the session userdata array. But the information is gone when I try to read it on an other page..

The native PHP sessions work just fine (tested it), so it must be something from CI.

I programmed a simple test page where I test the following:

- Set the session userdata.
- Test page shows the userdata correctly.
- Uncomment the set session data lines in the code of the controller and reload the page.
- Test page doesn't show the userdata.

The code of the controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

   public function index(){ 
        $data = null;

        $data['test'] = "Yeeeeh!!";
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }
}
```

Code of the view:

```
<?php
    echo $this->session->userdata('test');
?>
```

Comment: Please read the manual how the session helper works, *before* you ask questions. See here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Thx for the clear comment... I read the manual and did all the things it stated. I autoloaded the library, setted the session vdata and then try to read it..

Comment: So if you don't get any errors, you installed it OK. Now read the manual again, but this time about how to use it. Especially the part about how to name a session value.

Comment: I made a typing error in stackoverflow.. If you read the bullit list then in step 2 you'll read that the output is successfull.. And in step 4 not!

Comment: Okay the next step is to understand what a view is and how you pass variables into a view. See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: I know how a view works and how to pass variables to it. I want to read out the SESSION data. So i can just use $this->session. So the next step is to read the bullit list.

Comment: If you know that, what makes you believe that you could use `$this->session` in the view?

Comment: Because I use the `$this` reference for more then only the session library. You can use loaded `models`, `libraries`, `helpers`... And it works in step 2..

Comment: Step 2? What step 2? And you have not answered my question: what makes you believe that you could use `$this->session` in the view?

Comment: Step 2 of the bullit list in my post. Because the controller is the parent? When I use `print_r($this)` in the view then i can find my loaded libraries/models within the list.

Comment: Then debug your session object if it contains the data you ask for.

Comment: Try this. $this->session->set_userdata('test',"Yeah"); and then use echo $this->session->userdata('test');

Comment: Sorry for asking that but: What browser did you use for testing that? Could be IE? If you want to make a real test, try to print the session id, and check if it's going to change to every page request. If it's the case maybe you have a problem with cookies.

Comment: @Th3N3rD No probs, I used Chrome. I also checked the session id, and this would change sometimes indeed. But I have read that it didn't matter if this would happen. Because when CI renew the cookie data it also has to transfer the userdata from the old to the new. I can't find the article anymore.. But if the old one isn't found then it also woudn't hold any user data, so maybe it's a cookie problem. I already implemented the native PHP Session for the storing of the current user id, but I'm gonna test the cookies anyways.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CI's sessions are cookies, not PHP native sessions. Calling sessions in a view works (IIRC), but since your view is loaded in the same request the session is created, it won't be set.

You need to call it on another request (i.e. another controller), or set the session somewhere else (in another controller, via AJAX could work also), or use native PHP $_SESSION array instead.

I think your actual code is just a test case, otherwise why not just

```
public function index(){ 
        $data = null;

        $data['test'] = "Yeeeeh!!";
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }
```

in view:

```
<?php
  echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's indeed just a test case. I want to set the current loggedin user and want to be able to read this when needed. I think that i will use the native PHP sessions for this, and maybe encrypt the data with the encryption library.

Comment: the question is asking to store data into the session, you are passing it directly to th view.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the view display the session_id and not the "test" variable you created?

Did you test

```
<?php
echo $this->session->userdata('test');
```

?>

in the view file?

Comment: I made a typo in stackoverflow. sorry. The code in my view is as you say.